# Cancel all api request if the first one get error code in Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

In the backend, if I block a user the user get a 417 error code in every response and when my app get 417 it shows a dialog

So what I need that, the list of running APIs if the first one gets a 417 error code the other APIs procced are canceled.

I am using Retrofit 2.0 with okHttp and Interceptor

Comment: Do you want to cancel already outbound requests, or just stop any more from going out?  The second is much easier than the first.

Comment: i want to stop every req outbound and going out request

Comment: Stopping new requests is easy-  write a class that wraps your retrofit client and checks a variable to see if a 417 was ever seen or not.  Canceling requests in progress would require you to store all requests as you make them, and call cancel on them when you see a 417.  The harder part is keeping the list of only ongoing requests and not keeping the ones that are finished, that will take some bookkeeping.